# import Swiper show error by using react-native-swiper

Tags: react-native, react-native-swiper

I try to use swiper from this library https://github.com/leecade/react-native-swiper

Here is my dependencies:

```
"react": 16.3.1,
"react-native": "~0.55.2",
"react-native-swiper": "^1.5.13"
```

But when i just add this code `import Swiper from 'react-native-swiper';`

My component like:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import Swiper from 'react-native-swiper';

class Welcome extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Welcome</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default Welcome;
```

It will shows error even i don't use the `<Swiper />`

error:

```
Failed to load bundle
```

[image]

Check my terminal error shows:

```
error: bundling failed: Error: While trying to resolve module `react-native-swiper` from file `/Users/huaweb/ReactNativeProject/Huaweb/src/components/Welcome.js`, the package `/Users/huaweb/ReactNativeProject/Huaweb/node_modules/react-native-swiper/package.json` was successfully found. However, this package itself specifies a `main` module field that could not be resolved (`/Users/huaweb/ReactNativeProject/Huaweb/node_modules/react-native-swiper/index.js`. Indeed, none of these files exist:
```

I don't know what is `However, this package itself specifies a`main`module field that could not be resolved`

I can't figure it out. Is any thing i miss it ?

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the full error message?

Comment: I upload the error image on my question. Take a look please~

Comment: I see, does your terminal give you same error or does it show further detail to your error?

Comment: Here are some solutions which may work for you https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/17685

Comment: Thanks for your help , but i can't find how to fix my issue with this link and i update my terminal error information on my question.

Comment: @徐博俊 did you try another react-native library? Eg: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-swiper-flatlist

Answer (score 0):

In node_modules find the folder react-native-swiper and do so, It worked for me

replace :

```
module.exports = Swiper;
module.exports.default = Swiper;
```

by

```
export default Swiper
export {Swiper}
```

Answer (score 0):

try with:

import Swiper from 'react-native-swiper/src';